# How can I use services in another service inside one and the same bundle(module)?

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, blueprint-osgi

I have 2 budles in project. When first bundle is start second bundle use services from it. But How can I use service in service inside  bundle?

```
<service ref="EMUtilService" interface="domain.access.EMUtil"/>

    <bean id="EMUtilService" class="domain.access.impl.EMUtilImpl" scope="singleton">
        <jpa:context unitname="access" property="entityManager"/>
        <tx:transaction method="*" value="RequiresNew"/>
    </bean>

    <service ref="userService" interface="domain.access.UserService"/>

    <bean id="userService" class="domain.access.impl.UserServiceImpl" scope="singleton">
    </bean>
```

I want use `EMUtilService` in `userService` or in another simple classes.

my `EMUtilService`

```
public class EMUtilImpl implements EMUtil {
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }
}
```

I wan init `EntityManager` in this service and use it in another classes.

Answer (score 0):

Blueprint is largely inspired by Spring (it's the successor of Spring DM) and as such, it supports the same syntax for injecting beans/services into other beans. You can put an id on a bean definition, and inject this bean into a property of another bean :

```
<bean id="mybean" class="my.package.MyClass"/>

<bean id="myService" class="my.package.MyService">
   <property name="myProperty" ref="mybean"/>
</bean>
```